# How to map a joined-subclass with a composite key with non-matching column names

Tags: nhibernate

I have two tables, say:

```
PAYMENT
------------------------------
OrderId             INT    PK
PaymentId           INT    PK
Amount              FLOAT
ChildPaymentRowNum  INT

CARD_PAYMENT
------------------------------
OrderId             INT    PK
PaymentRowNum       INT    PK
CardType            STRING

CHEQUE_PAYMENT
------------------------------
OrderId             INT    PK
PaymentRowNum       INT    PK
CheckNumber         INT
```

No, I didn't make this DB and no I can't change it. I want to map `CARD_PAYMENT` and `CHEQUE_PAYMENT` as `joined-subclass`es of `PAYMENT`. The difference in this model from the examples I've found is that I'm both using a composite key *and* one of the column names in the foreign table doesn't match.

I think if it were not a composite key I could do this:

```
<joined-subclass name="CardPayment" table="CARD_PAYMENT" extends="Payment">
    <key column="PaymentRowNum" foreign-key="ChildPaymentRowNum">
</joined-subclass>
```

And if the names matched on the composite key I could do this:

```
<joined-subclass name="CardPayment" table="CARD_PAYMENT" extends="Payment">
    <key>
        <column="OrderId">
        <column="PaymentRowNum">
    </key>
</joined-subclass>
```

But, while I'd like to do something like this I'm pretty sure it's illegal:

```
<!-- NO GOOD -->
<joined-subclass name="CardPayment" table="CARD_PAYMENT" extends="Payment">
    <key>
        <column="OrderId" foreign-key="OrderId">
        <column="PaymentRowNum" foreign-key="ChildPaymentRowNum">
    </key>
</joined-subclass>
```

So, how would I do something like this?

**BONUS POINTS:** if you can tell me how to do it with `NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes`, but if not I can probably figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreign-key` attribute is used to specify the name of a foreign key constraint (not column!) that should be created by the NHibernate schema generation tool. It has no affect on NHibernate during runtime.

Why do you want to specify the key column name of the base class in the subclass key? Even the NHibernate documentation for `joined-subclass` uses different column names in both tables: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-joinedsubclass

Comment: Hmm... Okay, I could be missing something but I think the answer to your question is that the (primary) key for the base class is not the same key as the one that expresses the relationship. The PK for the base class is [`OrderId`,`PaymentId`], while the FK that expresses the subclass relationship is composed of [`OrderId`,`ChildPaymentRowNum`]. This being the case, do I need to be declaring the later pair as some kind of key on the base class instead?

Comment: @S'pht'Kr Oh, sorry, I missed the part that the PK not only uses different column names but also completely different values than the child keys. I've no idea how you could map that with NHibernate. As far as I know NHibernate requires that all entities in an inheritance mapping have the same id. That DB model is just wrong in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not happy with the DB...this example is a faked representation of the same scenario, and the real thing makes a tiny bit more sense, but not much really. If this isn't possible I'll be only slightly surprised, but it'll be the first time I've found something in NHibernate that wasn't! At least it's far, far more flexible than EntityFramework which wouldn't even let me define composite keys.